# implementing a socket.io chat app

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have created the beginnings of a chat app using socket.io through working on a Udemy tutorial, but the app doesn't seem to be working as it should. Since nobody is monitoring the tutorial's Q&A, I need to put my question to a broader audience.

With the code in the state it is in now, I should be able to enter messages into the app, but I can't. I'm getting a 404 error in the console, and it states that `service-worker.js` cannot be found. I have checked and re-checked my code against the instructor's on-screen code, and I can't find a fault. It's time to open up the discussion to the web.

Here is the code from the `application.js` file:

```
'use strict'

const socket = io()

const chatInput = document.querySelector('.chat-form input[type=text]')

chatInput.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  if (event.keycode !== 13)
    return

  event.preventDefault()

  const text = event.target.value.trim()
  if (text.length === 0)
    return

  socket.emit('chat:add', {
    message: text
  })

  event.target.value = ''
})
```

And here is the code from the `server.js`file:

```
'use strict'

const http = require('http')
const express = require('express')
const socketIo = require('socket.io')

const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'jade')

app.use(express.static('./public'))

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
  response.end('<h1>Hello world</h1>')
})

app.get('/home', (request, response) => {
  response.render('index', {title: 'TITLE'})
})

const server = new http.Server(app)
const io = socketIo(server)

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('client connected')
  socket.on('chat:add', data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('socket disconnected')
  })
})

const port = 3000
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`)
})
```

This code has also been copied to a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/pulamusic/04b16ca275fdc75c0bffc27bca97cb98) if that is more readable.

Comment: I don't see wrong with your code (at first glance). Try a different browser or check chrome://serviceworker-internals/ in Chrome and unregister anything related to localhost. I used this as reference: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

Comment: Thanks. The advice to look at `chrome://serviceworker-internals/` was helpful - I got rid of the error messages in the console. Still can't enter messages into the app, though.